# Sorting by category in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

such a problem: I made a sidebar and there is a list of categories in it, you need to change def get_queryset in such a way that when you click on a category, all posts with this category are shown. I need to store public = True and .order_by ('- data') in def get_queryset

**views.py**

```
class CategoryFilterView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
model = Post
template_name = 'news.html'
context_object_name = 'news'
permission_required = ('news.view_post', 'news.view_category')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('-data')
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)


class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Категория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

def __str__(self):
    return self.category_name

class Post(models.Model):
PostAuthor = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор поста')

PostNews = 'PN'
PostArticle = 'PA'

# «статья» или «новость»
POSITIONS = [
    (PostArticle, 'Статья'),
    (PostNews, 'Новость'),
]

postCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Категория поста',  through='PostCategory')
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название')
positions = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=POSITIONS, default=PostArticle, verbose_name='Тип поста')
category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_id')
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
data_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата редактирования')
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото', blank=True, default='/photos/def/1.jpg/')
previewName = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Превью поста')
text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст поста')
rating = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Рейтинг')
public = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')

def like(self):
    self.rating +=1
    self.save()

def dislike(self):
    self.rating -=1
    self.save()

def preview(self):
    return self.text[0:124] + '...'

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Пост'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f'/news/{self.pk}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u try it using a Q object to filter:

```
category = self.request.POST['category'] # this comes from frontend

filter_object = Q()

if category != '':
 filter_object &= Q(
  postCategory__category_name__icontains = category)

annex_data = Posts.objects.values('postCategory_id').filter(filter_object)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for writing, but unfortunately I need it through def_queryset @juan francisco quiñones romero